# Email sent via domain name address rejected as spam

Tags: email, domain, spam-prevention

I'm new to the site and this is my first question. I hope it's OK to post here as I'm not an administrator, just an ordinary computer user!

This is my problem - For my work, I use an email address ending with my domain name. Several clients receive my mails labelled as possible spam, or they are bounced back as spam.

I understand this is because I use my ISP (a French company called Free) to send and receive email, and that the problem comes from the conflict between my @domainname.com email address and the smtp.free.fr

Free and the domain name host each say it's the other's problem and won't help. I contacted an IT guy who wasn't interested in the job.

Is there a simple solution I could implement myself? I've read answers to what seem to be similar problems, but don't properly understand them.

Thanks and best regards,
Sandra

Comment: Do you have a server at home or do you pay someone for the email account? Or if you need to create a new user under your domain, where do you do that?

Comment: are you sending your mails to port 587 of smtp.free.fr?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your replies.
I pay Free for the internet connection and I pay domaine.fr to host my .com domain name. If I need to create a new user, I do it via domaine.fr

The outgoing port is 25 and the incoming port is 110.

Comment: Hi again - I read the info about creating an SPF record. Who would I need to contact to get that done? Sorry about the dumb questions, I am really at a loss here!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to pick a email service provider and send all mail using their SMTP server (with on *submission* port `587` instead of STMP on port`25`) instead of ISP's SMTP servers. This way you can prevent no-one else for using your domain as a legitimate sender.

Then, you need to set up [*Sender Policy Framework* (SPF)](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction) record for your domain. This you'd need to do even if you use ISP's SMTP server: you need to list the SMTP server as a permitted sender.